# Account based image pull permission in Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-service, azure-container-registry

Do we have any mechanism to allow user's to pull specified images only by using same Azure container registry.

As an example, let's say we have 2 clients ***(client1@mydomain.com, client2@mydomain.com)*** and 3 images ***(image A, Image B, Image C)*** in the same azure container registry ***(mydomain.azurecr.io)***.

- Scenario

  1. **client1@mydomain.com** allow to pull **image A, Image B,** from ACR ***(mydomain.azurecr.io)*** and restrict to pull **Image C.**
  2. **client2@mydomain.com** to allow **Image C** from ACR ***(mydomain.azurecr.io)*** and restrict to pull **image A, Image B.**

Please refer the below diagram,

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95FwH.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot achieve it in ACR. ACR only support to set permissions in the ACR level, not in the repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, is there any other workaround for this.

Comment: @anXler Currently, there are no other ways in only one ACR. You can use different ACRs and set different permissions for the users.

Comment: Thanks you @Charles Xu, appreciate you're responce

Comment: I have asked the very same question from Microsoft support and they informed me that, this is still on development process.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/903958-azure-container-registry/suggestions/31655977-configure-permissions-at-a-repository-level

Comment: @anXler Yeah, I think it's a necessary feature, a whole permission control only in one level is too simple and crude.